# Excel to nested Json including child elements into array

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to convert an Excel to nested JSON using Python where the repeated values go in as an array of elements.

Ex: structure of CSV

```
Manufacturer,oilType,viscosity
shell,superOil,1ova
shell,superOil,2ova
shell,normalOil,1ova
bp, power, 10bba
```

Should be displayed in JSON (expected output) as

```json
elements: [
    {
        "Manufacturer": "shell",
        "details": [
            {
                "OilType": "superOil",
                "Viscosity": [
                    "1ova",
                    "2ova"
                ]
            },
            {
                "OilType": "normalOil",
                "Viscosity": [
                    "1ova"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Manufacturer": "bp",
        "details": [
            {
                "OilType": "power",
                "Viscosity": [
                    "10bba"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have currently converted the CSV into JSON using `openpyxl` and the values are displayed for each of the headers in format like (Current output)

```json
[{Manufacturer: "shell", oilType: "superOil", Viscosity:"1ova"},{...},{...},...]
```

Please help in getting the expected output.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has actually nothing to do with `openpyxl` because you don't need to save into an Excel file.

You can do thought:

1. Load the csv (or Excel) into a pandas `DataFrame`
2. Group by Manufacturer and oil type
3. Dump into the format you want
4. Transform to JSON (either string or file)

In practice, that gives something like that:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("oil.csv")  # or read_excel if this is an Excel
oils = df.groupby(["Manufacturer", "oilType"]).aggregate(pd.Series.to_list)

elements = [
    {
        "Manufacturer": manufacturer,
        "Details": [
            {"OilType": o, "Viscosity": v}
            for o, v in data.droplevel(0).viscosity.items()
        ],
    }
    for manufacturer, data in oils.groupby(level="Manufacturer")
]

with open("oil.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump({"elements": elements}, f)
```

For information, `oils` would look like this:

```
                           viscosity
Manufacturer    oilType 
bp              power       [10bba]
shell           normalOil   [1ova]
                superOil    [1ova, 2ova]
```